Error Importing CSS in React Native with Expo and NativeWind: Numeric Escape Error
I am developing a React Native app using Expo, NativeWind, and Metro. I'm encountering a syntax error related to a CSS import when I try to start my project with npx expo start -c. Here are the details:
Web Bundling failed 9ms C:\...\my_app\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js (1 module)
error: SyntaxError: C:\...\my_app\global.css: The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0'. (1:17)

> 1 | import 'C:\...\...\my_app\node_modules\.cache\nativewind\global.css'
    |               ^

my_app\app\_layout.tsx
// nativewind
import "../global.css";

global.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    ".expo/types/**/*.ts",
    "expo-env.d.ts"
  ]
}

metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const { withNativeWind } = require('nativewind/metro');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = withNativeWind(config, { input: './global.css' });

metro.transformer.js
const upstreamTransformer = require("@expo/metro-config/babel-transformer");
const svgTransformer = require("react-native-svg-transformer");

module.exports.transform = async ({ src, filename, options }) => {
  // Use react-native-svg-transformer for SVG files
  if (filename.endsWith(".svg")) {
    return svgTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }
  // Pass the source through the upstream Expo transformer for other files
  return upstreamTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
};

package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/cli": "^0.18.10",
    "expo": "^51.0.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.11",
    "nativewind": "4.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1"
  },
  ...
}

Additional Information:
The file node_modules.cache\nativewind\global.css.web.css was created successfully.
I tried deleting node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file, and then reinstalling the packages but not not working.
